# Best way of declaring private variables in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, properties, private, instance-variables

I would like to know what the recommendations are for declaring private instance variables in cocoa. This question is in the context of developing apps on the iPhone.

I am aware of at least three ways of declaring private variables:

1. Declare them in the interface of the h file with the modifier @private:

   ```
   @interface MyClass : NSObject {  
     @private  
     NSObject * myPrivateVar;   
   }
   ```
2. Declare them in the implementation section of the m file:

   ```
   @implementation MyClass  
   NSObject * myPrivateVar;
   ```
3. Declare a property in the interface of the m file (not even declaring the variable itself):

   ```
   @interface MyClass ()  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myPrivateVar;  
   @end  
   @implementation  
   @synthesize myPrivateVar;
   ```

So far, I have used extensively 2 but recently came to realize this might be dangerous due to the lack of garbage collection.  Are there cases where it remains perfectly acceptable to use that method?

Is 3 more appropriate?  Does the answer depend on the object type (e.g. mutable/immutable)?

Pointers to reference material discussing the trade offs for using/not using properties in general also appreciated.

Comment: There is no garbage collection on the iPhone.

Comment: Since you wrote this, it is also possible to declare an iVar in the implementation, as so:
`@implementation MyClass
{ 
    NSObject * myPrivateVar;
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your three options have different semantics:

1. This creates an instance variable. Without garbage collection you need to `retain`/`release` objects you store into `myPrivateVar`.
2. This **does not** define an instance variable at all. Variables defined outside of the `@interface` and the scope of many method (or function) definitions are "global" - effectively class variables (which Objective-C has no special syntax for). Such a variable is shared by all instances of `MyClass`.
3. The difference between using a property (with or without the variable being explicitly declared) comes down to memory management. Defined as you have with `retain` means that there is no need for `retain`/`release` when you do not have garbage collection.

So don't use 2! Option 3 clearly has benefits if you don't have garbage collection, it provides some measure of abstraction over option 1, and is more costly - though you will probably not notice the difference outside of computationally intensive code which access the variable heavily.

**Update 2015**

Where *garbage collection* is used above *ARC* (automatic reference counting) is now more applicable (garbage collection is now deprecated). Also there is now a fourth option:

4. Declare them in the implementation section of the m file:

   ```
   @implementation MyClass  
   {
      NSObject * myPrivateVar;
   }
   ```

   Unlike option (2) this does declare an instance variable. The variable is private to the implementation, and with ARC memory management is  automatic. The choice between this and (3) [which incidentally also no longer requires the `@synthesize`] comes down to choice and need; properties give you dot syntax, the ability to customise the setter and/or getter, and the `copy` attribute for automatic copy on assignment, but if you need none of these you can simply use the an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks. I was so surprised option 2 was declaring a static that I wrote a small test to convince myself. Indeed, you were right. Little did I know.  Option 3 seems indeed the best approach for private variables that do not need to be static.